# React Native image stuttering

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue with background image loading in React Native.
Basically my local image take a time to show. This is not good because doesn't look as a professional app. So, take a look

[image]

Someone know how to solve this issue? I was searching about that and I found some workarounds like [this](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/progressive-image-loading-in-react-native-ecc88e724343) one But, this still not looks as a professional app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Image.prefetch](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/image.html#prefetch) method. It can improve loading time if you know what you're going to load in advance (you can check online example to see the difference in milliseconds). And it can be combined with other techniques like these progressive image loading and fade in.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching images to disk cache can also improve the UX of your app significantly. I wrote an article that describes such process [here](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/image-caching-in-react-native-96d8df33ca84).